# Concat two DataFrames on missing indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames and want to use the second one only on the rows whose index is not already contained in the first one.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

**Example:**

```
df_1
idx     val
0      0.32
1      0.54
4      0.26
5      0.76
7      0.23

df_2
idx     val
1     10.24
2     10.90
3     10.66
4     10.25
6     10.13
7     10.52

df_final
idx     val
0      0.32
1      0.54
2     10.90
3     10.66
4      0.26
5      0.76
6     10.13
7      0.23
```

Recap: I need to add the rows in `df_2` for which the index is not already in `df_1`.

---

**EDIT**

Removed some indices in `df_2` to illustrate the fact that all indices from `df_1` are not covered in `df_2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the wanted output by using the [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first) method of the DataFrame. From the documentation of the method:

> Combine two DataFrame objects and default to non-null values in frame calling the method. Result index columns will be the union of the respective indexes and columns

Example usage:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame([0.32,0.54,0.26,0.76,0.23], columns=['val'], index=[0,1,4,5,7])
df_1.index.name = 'idx'

df_2 = pd.DataFrame([10.56,10.24,10.90,10.66,10.25,10.13,10.52], columns=['val'], index=[0,1,2,3,4,6,7])
df_2.index.name = 'idx'

df_final = df_1.combine_first(df_2)
```

This will give the desired result:

```
In [7]: df_final
Out[7]:
       val
idx       
0     0.32
1     0.54
2    10.90
3    10.66
4     0.26
5     0.76
6    10.13
7     0.23
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = df_1.reindex(df_2.index).combine_first(df_2)
print (df)
       val
idx       
0     0.32
1     0.54
2    10.90
3    10.66
4     0.26
5     0.76
6    10.13
7     0.23
```

---

```
df = df_1.reindex(df_2.index).fillna(df_2)
print (df)
       val
idx       
0     0.32
1     0.54
2    10.90
3    10.66
4     0.26
5     0.76
6    10.13
7     0.23
```

Comment: I didn't make it obvious in my example, but the `df_2` index does not cover all the `df_1` index. Hence this method does not work as it is, it takes only the indices which appear in `df_2`.

Comment: I try test it, for me it works. Can you add it to samples where is problem in my solution? Thanks.

Comment: I have `len(df) = len(df_2)` when running either of your solutions. The indices which are in `df_1` but not in `df_2` are removed.

Comment: I cannot simulate it. I try same `length` and for me it works. I dont know what is problem :(

Comment: @Jivan You can achieve the wanted result by using `df_final =  df_1.combine_first(df_2)`.