# Add rows from one dataframe to another based on missing values in a given column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have been searching a long time for an answer but could not find it. I have two dataframes, one is `target`, the other `backup` which both have the same columns. What I want to do is to look at a given column and add all the rows from `backup` to `target` which are not in `target`. The most straightforward solution for this is:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

target = pd.DataFrame({
         "key1": ["K1", "K2", "K3", "K5"],
         "A": ["A1", "A2", "A3", np.nan],
         "B": ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B5"],
     })

backup = pd.DataFrame({
         "key1": ["K1", "K2", "K3", "K4", "K5"],
         "A": ["A1", "A", "A3", "A4", "A5"],
         "B": ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"],
     })

merged = target.copy()

for item in backup.key1.unique():
    if item not in target.key1.unique():
        merged = pd.concat([merged, backup.loc[backup.key1 == item]])

merged.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

giving

```py
  key1    A   B
0   K1   A1  B1
1   K2   A2  B2
2   K3   A3  B3
3   K5  NaN  B5
4   K4   A4  B4
```

Now I have tried several things using just pandas where none of them works.

1. [pandas concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```py
# Does not work because it creates duplicate lines and if dropped, the updated rows which are different will not be dropped -- compare the line with A or NaN

pd.concat([target, backup]).drop_duplicates()

  key1  A   B
0   K1  A1  B1
1   K2  A2  B2
2   K3  A3  B3
3   K5  NaN B5
1   K2  A   B2
3   K4  A4  B4
4   K5  A5  B5
```

2. [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```py
# Does not work because the backup would overwrite data in the target -- NaN

pd.merge(target, backup, how="right")

  key1  A   B
0   K1  A1  B1
1   K2  A   B2
2   K3  A3  B3
3   K4  A4  B4
4   K5  A5  B5
```

3. Importantly, it is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296798/merge-only-when-value-is-empty-null-in-pandas) since I do not want to have a new column and more importantly, the values are not `NaN` in `target`, they are simply not there. Furthermore, if then I would use what is proposed for merging the columns, the `NaN` in the `target` would be replaced by the value in `backup` which is unwanted.
4. It is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344900/concat-two-dataframes-on-missing-indices) which uses the [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) pandas because in that case the `NaN` is filled by the value from the `backup` which is wrong:

```py
target.combine_first(backup)

   key1 A   B
0   K1  A1  B1
1   K2  A2  B2
2   K3  A3  B3
3   K5  A4  B5
4   K5  A5  B5
```

5. Lastly,

```py
target.join(backup, on=["key1"])
```

gives me an annoying

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

which I really do not get since both are pure strings and the [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649853/trying-to-merge-2-dataframes-but-get-valueerror) does not work.

So I would like to ask, what am I missing? How can I do it using some `pandas` methods? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with filtered `backup` rows that do not exist in `target.key1` filtered by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
merged = pd.concat([target, backup[~backup.key1.isin(target.key1)]])
print (merged)
  key1    A   B
0   K1   A1  B1
1   K2   A2  B2
2   K3   A3  B3
3   K5  NaN  B5
3   K4   A4  B4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this with a 'subset' parameter in `df.drop_duplicates()`?

```
pd.concat([target, backup]).drop_duplicates(subset = "key1")
```

which gives output:

```
  key1    A   B
0   K1   A1  B1
1   K2   A2  B2
2   K3   A3  B3
3   K5  NaN  B5
3   K4   A4  B4
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. For some reason, this does not work on my dataset,it shows the complement (or something of that sort). I have not yet figured out why or why does my MRE not cover that but I wanted to state it in case someone was faster.